# Getting New Document button behaviour the same for Content types enabled for Office Web Apps

Tags: document-library, office-web-apps

If I create an OOTB document library, and click on "(+) new document" button, I get a panel appearing which allows me to select a document type of Word, Excel etc.

[image]

However, as soon as I turn on allow Content Types (Library Settings > Advanced Settings > Allow management of Content Type > Yes) this panel disappears and all I get is an upload box.

[image]

Is there a way to get the panel to appear if you keep "Allow management of content type" turned on? After adding my own content type, removing 'document' content type and then turning the management of content types off, I got the panel back again, and the documents created were of my content type, but this isn't any good if you have multiple content types. Is this a restriction in SharePoint? Or do I need to do something to my Content Types/Library to get this working?